# Simple login to session

Tags: session, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I work on simple project in .net core. It school task, so I do not need any advanced practices. Can you tell me what is the simplest way to set default view when session is null ? For example When user manually enter Url /Home/Tasks he will be redirected to Account/Login until enter correct login. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You achieve that simply use basic authentication. Choose Individual User Accounts option while creating new application:

[image]

After that take a look at the Startup.cs class and add following lines to `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{   
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Logoff");
    });
}
```

or

```
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
{
     options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
});
```

Ones this is done you can mark your controller with an [Authorize] attribute and all actions of that controller will require user to be logged in:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```